# @ActiveProfiles in class using Testcontainers but with no @Profile in main code

Tags: spring, profile, testcontainers

I currently study this kind of code.
In a test class I got something like:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestcontainersApplication.class, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ProductRepositoryTest extends ContainersEnvironment {

@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;
```

So, this is Testcontainers framework.
Normally, `@ActiveProfiles` work with an `@Profile` in the main code.

For example:

```
main code ==> @Profile("QA")
test package ==> @ActiveProfiles("QA")
```

My question is:
How does it come that in my project, I do NOT have any `@Profile("test")` annotation?
How Testcontainers works?
Does it make Junit test starting the application with a Spring profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, this is Testcontainers framework. Normally, @ActiveProfiles work
> with an @Profile in the main code.

1. `@ActiveProfiles` doesn't belong to Testcontainers library. It belongs to spring-framework.
2. The `@ActiveProfiles` annotation in a test class is instructing Spring to activate the "test" profile when **running the tests** in this class. This allows you to have specific configurations for your tests, here is some info: (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties#springProfile). It does **not** require the presence of a `@Profile` annotation with the same value in the main code.
3. How Testcontainers work is a different issue that needs to be considered separately from spring-profiles. But you can start by reading the documentation: https://testcontainers.com/getting-started

Comment: i know there is no link between @Profile/@ActiveProfiles and Testcontainers. But, as there is no Profile annotation in the code i study but there is an ActiveProfiles annotation, i wonder if Testcontainers do something special while starting tests. The repo i study is this one : https://github.com/thinkaboutit-github/tests-tutorial

Comment: You are writing: "Normally, ActiveProfiles work with an Profile in the main code", and that is false.
What do you mean, if Testcontainers do something special while starting tests? Which behaviour are you wondering?

Comment: when you say it is false, i do not undestand. Indeed, for me a profile mentioned in a ActiveProfiles annotation has an effect only if a Spring profile exists in the code (so a Profile spring annotation). If not, JUnit could not find the profile to activate. But, perhaps there is a subitlity regarding the functioning of Profile<==>ActiveProfiles relationship. If i am wrong, could you enlighten me ? thanks.

Comment: `ActiveProfiles`annotation does not require the presence of any `Profile` annotation in the main code. E.g. if you want to override some properties in test from application.yaml, you can annotate your test class with ActiveProfiles("mytest"), then create `application-mytest.yaml` in **test resources package** and override desired properties there

Comment: ok, i was wrong. your example is absolutly clear.